# TensorFlow: Node not found

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am training a neural network and have been running this code without any problems but **sometimes** (twice) I get an error `Not Found: FetchOutputs node not found` at the line `y_1 = sess.run(get_labels(step))` (See below).

`get_labels(step)` is a function to return the correct labels of my training images which is in a text file.

```
def get_labels(step):

    with open('labels.txt','r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        c = [[int(s) for s in row] for i,row in enumerate(reader) if i==step]

    label_numbers = np.array(c)

    # Convert to one-hot vectors
    numpy_label = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,5))
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        numpy_label[i,label_numbers[0][i]-1] = 1

    # Convert to tensor
    y_label = tf.convert_to_tensor(numpy_label,dtype=tf.float32)

    return y_label
```

This is my main function:

```
def main():

    # Placeholder for correct labels
    y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[BATCH_SIZE,5])

    < Other functions etc. >

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

    for step in range(1000):

        # Get labels for current batch
        y_1 = sess.run(get_labels(step))

        # Train
        sess.run([train_step],feed_dict={y_label:y_1})

        < Other stuff like writing summaries, saving variables etc. >

    sess.close()
```

From reading some of the issues on GitHub, I know this is to do with the fact that I call `y_1 = sess.run(get_labels(step))` **after** `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)` but I don't understand:

1. why it works most of the time, but occasionally doesn't?
2. Is `y_1 = sess.run(get_labels(step))` adding or modifying nodes in the graph? I thought I was just running a node `get_labels(step)` that was already defined in the graph. I tried finalizing the graph before starting the queue runners but that gave me the error that finalized graphs cannot be modified.
3. What would be the proper way to write the code? Usually I just restart my program and it is fine - but clearly I am not doing it the proper way.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I think it might be important to mention that this happens when I am trying to run a TensorFlow script in a separate screen on a server i.e. I have one screen running a TensorFlow script and now I create a new screen to run a different TensorFlow script. I just started using screens so I might be missing something fundamental about how they work.